# Can cloud firestore realistically be used for syncing a game between players?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking at using cloud firestore to sync a multiplayer web game between players. However, this game involves continuous motion, like a player dragging a piece from one place to another. This would involve a stream of writes as its position changes. Given that the free plan is 20k free writes per day, and 20k writes can be done by a dozen players in a few minutes in this case, I worry that the cost would rapidly spiral out of control.

Is it impossible to do this sort of thing with firestore? I'm basically talking about a continuous websocket connection keeping the game data synced between players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits of Firestore are [well-documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).  You haven't really said what hard limits you're concerned about exceeding.  The only thing you've indicated is limits regarding the perpetual free tier, which can be easily exceeded by simply paying for the product based on your usage.

If you're not willing to pay for the service based on your needs, then you should probably look for another service.  If you are willing to pay, then you need to do the math to figure out what your specific needs are, and if they can be met by the documented limits.

In the absence of more specific information about what you're trying to achieve, there's not much else that can be said.

Comment: Your point is valid. I am willing to pay though; I'm just having trouble envisioning how high the costs would go for my case.

Comment: As I said, that's a matter of doing the math using your projected usage patterns.